# Cleaning up a parent theme and creating a child theme.

Tags: parent-child-theme

We are in the process of creating a child theme for a theme that is being used: Ultimo. A number of customisations were made to the parent theme which should have been made to a child theme. We do not have a comprehensive list of those changes.

Is there a means of comparing the Original files of the theme and the customised theme to highlight the changes so that we can transfer these across from parent to child theme?

Thanks

Comment: I would commit the original version in SVN or Git and then I would commit the newer customized version and then compare them both to see what are the differences

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few ways of doing this.

1. Simply commit the original unchanged version to some form of source control and then make your changes and the source control software should highlight the changes.
2. Using a [magerun](https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun) plugin from [Kalen Jordan](https://github.com/kalenjordan/magerun-addons). This will allow you to specify two themes and then the output will be the differences between the two themes.